# Using tapply to match at least one of multiple variables

Tags: r, dataframe, summary, tapply

I have a set of data which contains information about customers and how much they have spent, each customer only appears once.Example:

```
customer<-c("Andy","Bobby","Oscar","Oliver","Jane","Cathy","Emma","Chris")
age<-c(25,34,20,36,23,35,34,22)
category<-c("A","B","B","A","C","B","C","A")
moneyspent<-c(100,100,200,200,400,400,500,200)

data<-data.frame(customer=customer,age=age,category=category,moneyspent=moneyspent)
```

If I want to calculate the average amount of money spent by categories, I can use tapply:

```
tapply(data$moneyspent,data$category,mean)
```

which gives:

```
  A      B      C 
mean1  mean2  mean3
```

However, I now want to find the average amount of money spent by category OR age. All consumers who have at least one of these features in common must be together.In the example the result I am aiming for is:

```
Group 1    Group 2
 mean1      mean2
```

Where group1 only has category A and group2 has category B, but because one of the costumers of B have the same age (34) of at least one costume of group C, group2 has category C too.

In my database I have several more categories and ages and I have to compute which groups should be formed.

Comment: Do you want the function to compute which groups should be together or is that known in advance? And do you have many more groups in your real data?

Comment: Your description "average amount of money spent by gender OR age" doesn't make much sense since there's no gender column and the category column consists of 3 categories whereas gender mostly has only two distinctions (with some exceptions indeed). Also the OR is not clear how you mean it.

Comment: You're right, i will correct that.

Answer (score 1):

We may need to create the grouping variable using `==`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(grp = paste0("Group", (category != "A")+1)) %>% 
   summarise(moneyspent = mean(moneyspent))
```

---

If we want the `tapply`

```
with(data, tapply(moneyspent, paste0('Group', (category != "A") +1), FUN = mean))
#  Group1   Group2 
#166.6667 320.0000
```

Comment: This works only with the given example. In the full database, I have more categories with different combinations of age.

Comment: @LucasMartinuzzo  You said specifically `B and C are together because they share the age 34.`  Here I am only grouping based on 'A' and all others will be grouped as group2.  I think you haven't included some info in the post